# How do you cross-sectionally standardize a variable?

Tags: portfolio, factor-models, fama-french, quantitative

i am doing research on a so-called carbon beta where I made a portfolio that takes a short position in 'green' stocks and a long position in 'brown' stocks, from a period of 2005 until 2020.  So from the brown minus green portfolio I generated one beta per company in my sample (750) through 750 time series regressions. So I have the variable Carbon beta. But how can I from there get the carbon beta cross sectionally standardized? Just so it is more clear with regards to my data it is monthly and i have a number of firm characteristics on a monthly basis too. So I would like to run a regression from the cross sectionally standardized variable on lagged firm characteristics, but how can I get the variable cross sectionally standardized?
I've put two screenshots from my reference paper in this post.
Hopefully some of you can help me out!

Cheers

[image]
[image].

Comment: Let's say Carbon (C) is the variable of interest, suppose in January 2005 the average $C_i$ for all companies (all $i$) is $\mu$ and the standard deviation is $\sigma$, then the cross sectionally standardised C is ${C}_i'=\frac{C_i-\mu}{\sigma}$. The same in Feb 2005, using the $\mu,\sigma$ for all companies for that month. The goal is that the C' have zero mean and unit standard deviation in each month.

Comment: Hi Nbbo2 thanks for your answer! But I estimated one carbon beta for every stock. So wouldn't this formula give the same answer for every for every month?

Comment: If you have one variable for every stock then of course it is different from having one variable for every stock and every month. I misunderstood the situation.